# Как запустить десктоп приложение (JavaFX) на Android?

Tags: java, android, javafx

Есть JavaFX проект, который работает на дескотпе. Нужно запустить эту программу на Android. Возможно ли это, или придётся в ручную всё переписывать?

Comment: Однозначно переписывать

Comment: @woesss я бы так не сказал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, [можно](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Building%20and%20deploying%20JavaFX%20Applications), если порт использовать. Даже на [iOS можно](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial5).

С помощью [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/) можно это делать, там под капотом [JavaFX порт](http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/).

Переписать кое-что, явно, придётся. Но это не то же самое, что перепилить всё на Android SDK.