# Запуск Java приложения с GUI на смартфоне

Tags: java, android, gui, mobile-development

Можно ли как-то запустить Java проект с использованием GUI на мобильном устройстве?

Comment: Если мобильная разработка - то да, конечно. Как иначе-то?
Если бильярд отрисовывали, то попробуйте онлайн компиляторы, авось получится. https://www.compilejava.net/

Comment: Конечно, бо́льшая часть приложений в Google Play - это java-приложения с GUI.

Comment: Да, можно. Андроид сам - ява проект с использованием гуи, запускаемый на мобильном устройстве.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin что такое бильярд? GUI для десктопа?

Comment: @АнтонСорокин он-лайн компилятором пробуйте. Их много.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за ответ, а если я писал не в андроид студио а в intelliJ idea, это не имеет значение?

Comment: @gnomekonom да имеет, в мобильных операционных системах абсолютно иной жизненный цикл приложений.

Comment: Т.е. нельзя запустить такой проект, верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java-проект для десктопа с GUI на Swing, AWT, SWT, JavaFX и тп. нельзя запустить на андроид-смартфоне без существенной переделки.

В первую очередь полнстью переписав всю GUI-часть, так как андроид имет свой собственный GUI, никак не совместимый с вышеперечисленными.

Так же структура  андроид-приложения кардинально отличается от структуры десктоп-приложения, начиная от точки входа и заканчивая взаимодействием с переферией.

Android имеет собственный фреймворк взаимодействия с системой (API Android) никаким образом не совместимый с десктопом, но совешенно необходимый для работы программы.

Фактически от десктоп-приложения на Java при переносе его на платформу Android останется только какая-то незначительная часть бизнес-логики, так, взаимодействие с сетью, базой данных и др. в андроид реализуется иначе и десктопный код будет почти бесполезен (остануться только сами запросы).

В завершение - программы Android имеют собственный формат APK. Чтобы просто запустить на андроид-смартфоне программу с форматом JAR нужно приложить некоторое количество усилий, в стоке андроид не дает возможности исполнить такой формат программ.
Страдает совместимость и на уровне VM. в андроид используется виртуальная машина ART (ранее Dalvik), в десктопе JavaVM - это тоже потенциальный источник проблем.

PS: вообще есть обходные пути: какие то порты и попытки реализовать кроссплатформенность (как [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735787/177345)), но результат скорее всего будет плачевным. Так же есть некоторое количество java-эмуляторов под Android, насколько они справятся с задачей тоже вопрос открытый.